# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in this() of Grails Domain Class

Tags: grails, groovy

I am working on a split Grails-Project, see here: [grails3 using a plugin for domain classes, specifically spring security User/Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888729/grails3-using-a-plugin-for-domain-classes-specifically-spring-security-user-rol)

Basically I am trying to put my Domain Classes into a plugin that can be used in multiple other projects.

I am getting this Exception when trying to start my Server:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at wcommon.WebsiteRole.<init>(WebsiteRole.groovy:15)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:9)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ron.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:437)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:430)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:406)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:240)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.spmework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at webp.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
:WebP:bootRun FAILED
```

I have no idea at all why this happens.
The line in question is a call to this()
Why would that throw such an exception?
My initial reaction was to remove this() and add an empty default constructor to the class, but that apparently broke the Dependency Injection, which caused the issue described in the question I liked above.

Code involved from my side is:

```
package wcommon

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='authority')
@ToString(includes='authority', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class WebsiteRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String authority

    WebsiteRole(String authority) {
        **this();** // line 15
        this.authority = authority
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
}


import grails.core.GrailsApplication
import wcommon.WebsiteUserWebsiteRole;

class BootStrap {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        **WebsiteUserWebsiteRole.initDefaults(grailsApplication)** //line 9
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

And the initDefaults function looks like this:

```
**static def initDefaults(GrailsApplication grailsApplication) {
    def patientRole = new WebsiteRole("ROLE_PATIENT").save();
    def adminRole = new WebsiteRole("ROLE_ADMIN").save()
    def doctorRole = new WebsiteRole("ROLE_DOCTOR").save()
    def nurseRole = new WebsiteRole("ROLE_NURSE").save()
    def serverRole = new WebsiteRole("ROLE_SERVER").save()

    def user1 = new WebsiteUser("admin", "password").save()
    WebsiteUserWebsiteRole.create user1, adminRole, true

    def user2 = new WebsiteUser("doctor", "password").save()
    WebsiteUserWebsiteRole.create user2, doctorRole, true

    def user3 = new WebsiteUser("nurse", "password").save()
    WebsiteUserWebsiteRole.create user3, nurseRole, true


}**
```

**EDIT:**
Using Grails Version 3.1.1

java -version is 1.7.0_79

spring security plugin is 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'

I am not quite sure which Database version I am using, I am just using the by default included h2, the dependency just says:
runtime "com.h2database:h2"

The Project setup in general is that my Domain classes are in one project, which is a plugin project.
The Project that has the issues includes the Domain classes via
compile project(':WebCommon')
in the dependencies. Compile works fine.

**EDIT 2:**
So if I remove the this() and add a default constructor it does not throw the exception, however the dependency injection of the spring security service in this class does not work:

```
package wcommon

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService;
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class WebsiteUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    public SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    WebsiteUser() {

    }

    WebsiteUser(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
    }

    Set<WebsiteRole> getAuthorities() {
        WebsiteUserWebsiteRole.findAllByWebsiteUser(this)*.websiteRole
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        println springSecurityService // prints null
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

After I changed the property from just def springSecurityService to public SpringSecurityService it told me that an indirect dependency to HttpServletRequest. Adding these dependencies to the plugin project fixes that, but this doesn't change anything about the injection not working:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
```

I thought that my changes to the User and Role classes to fix the this() issue caused the dependency injection problem. But maybe I am wrong and both of the issues are caused by something else, probably related to my project setup.
I dunno, this is all really confusing, been fighting with grails for since yesterday.

**EDIT:**
To get it to work I now first fixed the Exception by removing this() and adding the default constructor and then I injected a springSecurityService into the Bootstrap of my main project that is used to set a static public field on the class in the plugin project that ssneeds the springSecurityService.
Ugly, but it works better than anything I've tried so far.
... okay actually now this simple test of a controller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SERVER'])
class ApiController {

    def index() {
        render getAuthenticatedUser() as JSON
    }
}
```

throws a MissingMethodException about getAuthenticatedUser()

That Controller was added via create-controller
I guess this whole "split the project into multiple parts" isn't working at all and broke something very very deep down that causes all these issues to show up. I think instead of trying to split my project I'll just make a single web-app project that is configured with a flag that tells it which functions to activate and deactivate....

If somebody can tell me how to do a properly split grails project with common domain objects in a common library please see this question and post there:
[grails3 using a plugin for domain classes, specifically spring security User/Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888729/grails3-using-a-plugin-for-domain-classes-specifically-spring-security-user-rol)

Comment: Please show code of `wcommon.WebsiteRole` - bold 15 line and code of `BootStrap.groovy` - bold 9 line

Comment: Why are you invoking `this()` in a class that does not have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: I did not write that code, it was generated by the grails spring security plugin via the command s2-quickstart. Adding this() fixes the issue, but it isn't supposed to be there, from what I read elsewhere the no-arg constructor is supposed to be generated somehow and is important for the dependency injection. Adding the no-args constructors causes dependency injection in my user class to fail.
In another project the generated Role and User class also call this() while not implementing it and it works there.

Comment: Moreover which versions of Grails, spring-security, db and jdk are you using?

Comment: "I did not write that code, it was generated by the grails spring security plugin via the command s2-quickstart. "  - That surprises me.  That is a bug in the plugin.

Comment: I made a new simple project as one project and used s2-quickstart and there the this() makes no issues. So while it might just be invalid, in that more typical use-case it does not cause errors. Somehow.

Comment: This tutorial shows the generated code, which also has this() but no default constructor: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove all of the constructors from those classes (the `WebsiteUser`, `WebsiteRole`, and `WebsiteUserWebsiteRole` classes). This should also fix the bean injection problem. Instead of calling them in your init, you can all the map style constructor.

`static def initDefaults(GrailsApplication grailsApplication) {
    def patientRole = new WebsiteRole(authority: "ROLE_PATIENT").save();
...
    def userX = new WebsiteUser(username:"nurse", password:"password").save()
    WebsiteUserWebsiteRole.create user3, nurseRole, true
}`

Comment: Removing this() fixes that one specific issue, however the other issues described in edits remain. I really have no idea anymore where to even start to describe what is going wrong. It seems nothing works at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'Basically I am trying to put my Domain Classes into a plugin that can be used in multiple other projects'? It seems like maybe you should look into Spring Security CAS.

Comment: I'll have some domain classes, like "Person", "Role", "Group", "Medication", etc... that should be available on two different grails projects as Domain classes. These include the User and Role classes, but there are more.
Basically all I want is to put my domain classes into a library.

Comment: You can explore creating a grail plugin and hosting in a local repository. https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#plugins

Comment: The multi projects and plugins part of that documentation were my starting point for what I've been trying since yesterday. The two questions I made on stackoverflow summarize how little success I've had with that. It just doesn't work. Multiple errors occur, but I never get rid of all of them. It does not seem that there is a working example of this for grails 3.1.3

Comment: Create a new SO question for the next error you receive after fixing the relevant one in this question, then link the question here and I will do my best to answer it.

Comment: thank you :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900094/gorm-fails-to-realize-domain-classes-from-a-plugin-are-gorm-classes

Comment: Also, if this answer fixed this specific issue could you please accept it?